# [SOLVED]Kinectv2 not working with real ur5 but does in simulation

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I am using the UR5 with a own designed gripper as end-effector and KinectV2 to 'map' the environment so that the UR5 will avoid collisions with a human it might be working with. I have run some tests:

- Simulated UR5 and simulated Kinect in gazebo. I can see the 'octomap' getting added to the planning scene in moveit.rviz and the UR5 avoids collisions with object placed in Gazebo.
- Simulated UR5 in Gazebo and real Kinect, same as above.
- Real UR5 and real Kinect. I cannot see the planning scene being added in moveit.rviz.

I get a warning from moveit that says:

```
[ WARN] [1516619887.119811534]: The complete state of the robot is not yet known.  Missing driver_arm_joint
```

Where `driver_arm_joint` is the joint that controls the gripper state.

My suggestion is that moveit cannot use the planning scene it is creating because the complete state of the robot is not yet known.

UPDATE:
My gripper also becomes uncontrollable when launching the real UR5 and Kinectv2.

FINAL UPDATE:
First I remapped the topic /joint_states (published by ur_modern_driver) to /joint_states_ur5. Then I wrote a node that subscribes to the /joint_states_ur5 topic and add a sensors_msgs/JointState message to the tuple of the gotten published by the ur_driver. Then I republish the message under the topic /joint_states. The python node is shown below.

```
import math
import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import JointState
from std_msgs.msg import Bool


class ur5_republisher():
    def __init__(self):
        rospy.init_node('Cmd_Scaler')
        self.pub = rospy.Publisher('/joint_states', JointState, queue_size=10)
        rospy.Subscriber("/joint_states_ur5", JointState, self.joint_state_callback)

        self.name = 'driver_arm_joint'
        self.position = 0
        self.velocity = 0
        self.effort = 0

    def appendT(self,t,x):
    l = list(t)
    l.append(x)
    return tuple(l)

    def joint_state_callback(self, data):
        data.name.append(self.name)
    data.position = self.appendT(data.position, self.position)
    data.velocity = self.appendT(data.velocity, self.position)
    data.effort = self.appendT(data.effort, self.position)
       self.pub.publish(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ur5_r = ur5_republisher()
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
    # self.cycle()
    rospy.spin()
```

My question is:
Is there a way to initialize the endeffector group such that you define a start state? Currently this is the content of the srdf:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!--This does not replace URDF, and is not an extension of URDF.
    This is a format for representing semantic information about the robot structure.
    A URDF file must exist for this robot as well, where the joints and the links that are referenced are defined
-->
<robot name="ur5">
    <!--GROUPS: Representation of a set of joints and links. This can be useful for specifying DOF to plan for, defining arms, end effectors, etc-->
    <!--LINKS: When a link is specified, the parent joint of that link (if it exists) is automatically included-->
    <!--JOINTS: When a joint is specified, the child link of that joint (which will always exist) is automatically included-->
    <!--CHAINS: When a chain is specified, all the links along the chain (including endpoints) are included in the group. Additionally, all the joints that are parents to included links are also included. This means that joints along the chain and the parent joint of the base link are included in the group-->
    <!--SUBGROUPS: Groups can also be formed by referencing to already defined group names-->
    <group name="manipulator">
        <chain base_link="base_link" tip_link="ee_link" />
    </group>
    
    <group name="endeffector">
        <link name="mount_link"/>
        <link name="plate_link"/>
        <link name="driver_arm_link"/>
        <link name="driven_arm_link"/>
        <link name="left_arm_front_link"/>
        <link name="left_arm_back_link"/>
        <link name="right_arm_front_link"/>
        <link name="right_arm_back_link"/>
        <link name="left_finger_link"/>
        <link name="right_finger_link"/>
        <link name="gripper_ee_link"/>
    </group>

    <group_start_state name="start_gripper" group="endeffector">
        <joint name="driver_arm_joint" value="0"/>
    </group_start_state>
    <!-- Home state for manipulator group -->
    <group_state name="home" group="manipulator">
        <joint name="elbow_joint" value="0" />
        <joint name="shoulder_lift_joint" value="0" />
        <joint name="shoulder_pan_joint" value="0" />
        <joint name="wrist_1_joint" value="0" />
        <joint name="wrist_2_joint" value="0" />
        <joint name="wrist_3_joint" value="0" />
    </group_state>

    <!-- Up state for manipulator group -->
    <group_state name="up" group="manipulator">
        <joint name="elbow_joint" value="0" />
        <joint name="shoulder_lift_joint" value="-1.5707" />
        <joint name="shoulder_pan_joint" value="0" />
        <joint name="wrist_1_joint" value="-1.5707" />
        <joint name="wrist_2_joint" value="0" />
        <joint name="wrist_3_joint" value="0" />
    </group_state>
    <!--END EFFECTOR: Purpose: Represent information about an end effector.-->
    <end_effector name="moveit_ee" parent_link="ee_link" group="endeffector" parent_group="manipulator"/>
    <!--VIRTUAL JOINT: Purpose: this element defines a virtual joint between a robot link and an external frame of reference (considered fixed with respect to the robot)
    <virtual_joint name="fixed_base" type="fixed" parent_frame="world" child_link="base_link" />
-->
    <!--DISABLE COLLISIONS: Within the robot-->
    <disable_collisions link1="base_link" link2="shoulder_link" reason="Adjacent" />
    <disable_collisions link1="ee_link" link2="wrist_1_link" reason="Never" />
    <disable_collisions link1="ee_link" link2="wrist_2_link" reason="Never" />
    <disable_collisions link1="ee_link" link2="wrist_3_link" reason="Adjacent" />
    <disable_collisions link1="forearm_link" link2="upper_arm_link" reason="Adjacent" />
    <disable_collisions link1="forearm_link" link2="wrist_1_link" reason="Adjacent" />
    <disable_collisions link1="shoulder_link" link2="upper_arm_link" reason="Adjacent" />
    <disable_collisions link1="wrist_1_link" link2="wrist_2_link" reason="Adjacent" />
    <disable_collisions link1="wrist_1_link" link2="wrist_3_link" reason="Never" />
    <disable_collisions link1="wrist_2_link" link2="wrist_3_link" reason="Adjacent" />
    <disable_collisions link1="gripper_ee_link" link2="shoulder_link" reason="Never"/>
    <disable_collisions link1="gripper_ee_link" link2="forearm_link" reason="Never"/>
    <disable_collisions link1="gripper_ee_link" link2="upper_arm_link" reason="Never"/>
    <disable_collisions link1="gripper_ee_link" link2="wrist_1_link" reason="Never"/>
    <disable_collisions link1="gripper_ee_link" link2="wrist_2_link" reason="Never"/>
    <disable_collisions link1="gripper_ee_link" link2="wrist_3_link" reason="Never"/>
    <!-- DISABLE COLLISIONS: Within the end-effector -->
    <disable_collisions link1="ee_link" link2="mount_link" reason="Adjacent"/>
    <disable_collisions link1 ="wrist_3_link" link2="mount_link" reason="Adjacent"/>
    <disable_collisions link1="mount_link" link2="plate_link" reason="Adjacent"/>
    <disable_collisions link1="plate_link" link2="driver_arm_link" reason="Adjacent"/>
    <disable_collisions link1="plate_link" link2="driven_arm_link" reason="Adjacent"/>
    <disable_collisions link1="plate_link" link2="left_arm_front_link" reason="Adjacent"/>
    <disable_collisions link1="plate_link" link2="left_arm_back_link" reason="Adjacent"/>
    <disable_collisions link1="plate_link" link2="right_arm_front_link" reason="Adjacent"/>
    <disable_collisions link1="plate_link" link2="right_arm_back_link" reason="Adjacent"/>
    <disable_collisions link1="driver_arm_link" link2="driven_arm_link" reason="Adjacent"/>
    <disable_collisions link1="left_arm_front_link" link2="left_finger_link" reason="Adjacent"/>
    <disable_collisions link1="left_arm_back_link" link2="left_finger_link" reason="Adjacent"/>
    <disable_collisions link1="right_arm_front_link" link2="right_finger_link" reason="Adjacent"/>
    <disable_collisions link1="right_arm_back_link" link2="right_finger_link" reason="Adjacent"/>
</robot>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280451/%5Bsolved%5Dkinectv2-not-working-with-real-ur5-but-does-in-simulation/) by [EdwinvanEmmerik](https://answers.ros.org/users/32311/edwinvanemmerik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2018-01-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-23**:
re: your edit: take a look at the `source_list` parameter of the [wiki/joint_state_publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/joint_state_publisher#Parameters).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-23**:
It would also be nice if you could post your approach as an answer, and then accept your own answer.

That way it's a bit more obvious where the question ends and the answer starts.

**Comment by [EdwinvanEmmerik](https://answers.ros.org/users/32311/edwinvanemmerik/) on 2018-01-29**:
@gvdhoorn Thank you for reminding me of the source_list param. I gave an answer to my own question like you asked. Altough I can't accept my own answer as correct because I don't have enough 'karma'. Would be nice if you could do that, if you agree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to find the problem and solve it: I found out that the error I was having came from line 1188 from this header,
http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/moveit_ros_planning/html/planning__scene__monitor_8cpp_source.html

Then I realized that the ur_modern_driver is keeping the /joint_states topic occupied so I remapped the /joint_states topic to /joint_states_ur5 by adding this line to the spawning of the ur_driver node(ur_modern_driver/launch/ur_common.launch):

```
<node name="ur_driver" pkg="ur_modern_driver" type="ur_driver" output="screen">
....
    <remap from="joint_states" to="joint_states_ur5"/> <!-- THIS -->
....
</node>
```

Then I wrote a node that subscribes to the /joint_states_ur5 topic and add a sensors_msgs/JointState message to the tuple of the gotten published by the ur_driver. Then I republish the message under the topic /joint_states. The python node is shown below(FIRST NODE).

NOTE: For the updated python node (that includes setting the self.position based on a boolean rosparam look for the SECOND NODE).

FIRST NODE:

```
import math
import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import JointState
from std_msgs.msg import Bool


class ur5_republisher():
    def __init__(self):
        rospy.init_node('Cmd_Scaler')
        self.pub = rospy.Publisher('/joint_states', JointState, queue_size=10)
        rospy.Subscriber("/joint_states_ur5", JointState, self.joint_state_callback)

        self.name = 'driver_arm_joint'
        self.position = 0
        self.velocity = 0
        self.effort = 0

    def appendT(self,t,x):
    l = list(t)
    l.append(x)
    return tuple(l)

    def joint_state_callback(self, data):
        data.name.append(self.name)
    data.position = self.appendT(data.position, self.position)
    data.velocity = self.appendT(data.velocity, self.velocity)
    data.effort = self.appendT(data.effort, self.effort)
       self.pub.publish(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ur5_r = ur5_republisher()
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
    # self.cycle()
    rospy.spin()
```

SECOND NODE:

```
import math
import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import JointState
from std_msgs.msg import Bool

class ur5_republisher():
    def __init__(self):
        rospy.init_node('Cmd_Scaler')
        self.pub = rospy.Publisher('/joint_states', JointState, queue_size=10)
        rospy.Subscriber("/joint_states_ur5", JointState, self.joint_state_callback)
        self.name = 'driver_arm_joint'
        self.position = self.checkGripperState()
        self.velocity = 0
        self.effort = 0
    def appendT(self,t,x):
        l = list(t)
        l.append(x)
        return tuple(l)
    def checkGripperState(self):
        try:
            gripper_state = rospy.get_param('/bool_gripperOpen_param')
            if(gripper_state):
                gripper_position = 0.25
                return gripper_position
            if not(gripper_state):
                gripper_position = 0.0
                return gripper_position
        except KeyError:
            gripper_state = 0.0
            print("rosparam, bool_gripperOpen_param not set")
            return gripper_state
    def joint_state_callback(self, data):
        data.name.append(self.name)
        data.position = self.appendT(data.position, self.position)
        data.velocity = self.appendT(data.velocity, self.velocity)
        data.effort = self.appendT(data.effort, self.effort)
        self.pub.publish(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ur5_r = ur5_republisher()
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        # self.cycle()
        rospy.spin()
```

---

Originally posted by [EdwinvanEmmerik](https://answers.ros.org/users/32311/edwinvanemmerik/) with karma: 115 on 2018-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [raequin](https://answers.ros.org/users/33937/raequin/) on 2018-03-08**:
Can you explain why you did not have to remap the joint_states topic when working with a simulated UR5 and gripper? Also, what do you mean by " keeping the /joint_states topic occupied?"  I ask because it seems like the mobile base on my UR10 application is not getting to publish its joint states.

**Comment by [EdwinvanEmmerik](https://answers.ros.org/users/32311/edwinvanemmerik/) on 2018-03-11**:
@raequin When one is using a simulated robot. Using the URDF (where the gripper is implemented) all the states are part of the joint_states topic. However, when working with the real UR5 the ur_driver.cpp doesn't include the implemented gripper into the joint_states topic the ur_driver publishes

**Comment by [EdwinvanEmmerik](https://answers.ros.org/users/32311/edwinvanemmerik/) on 2018-03-11**:
@raequin I would suggest you run the 'rostopic echo joint_states' command . From there you would be able to see if your mobile base is added to the tuple on the 'joint_states' topic.

**Comment by [karelgtr](https://answers.ros.org/users/58626/karelgtr/) on 2020-10-13**:
Thank you so much for this! My joint_states topic was also occupied by one of my robots. I tried to solve my problem using source_list and joining topics but I couldn't make it work, joint_states would not be updated at all. I solved my problem by republishing to joint_states as you did! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.  Is there an error in the following?

```
    data.position = self.appendT(data.position, self.position)
    data.velocity = self.appendT(data.velocity, self.position)
    data.effort = self.appendT(data.effort, self.position)
```

It seems like it should be

```
    data.position = self.appendT(data.position, self.position)
    data.velocity = self.appendT(data.velocity, self.velocity)
    data.effort = self.appendT(data.effort, self.effort)
```

**edit:** My intention was for this to just be a comment on the accepted answer, not a separate answer.  Oops.

---

Originally posted by [raequin](https://answers.ros.org/users/33937/raequin/) with karma: 368 on 2018-03-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [EdwinvanEmmerik](https://answers.ros.org/users/32311/edwinvanemmerik/) on 2018-03-08**:
@raequin Yes! You are completely right, thanks for pointing it out. I will edit the post.